# SELECT not working when it follows an UPDATE

Tags: php, sql

I'm using PHP to send a query to Sql Server. The problem is, my "SELECT 1 AS updateResults" statement doesn't work if it's done after the UPDATE statement. A resource is returned to PHP but it doesn't have any rows.

Here's a simplified version of my query:

```
--SELECT 1 AS updateResults --if this is done before the UPDATE, a row gets returned

UPDATE theTable SET theValue = 'x' WHERE theRow = '5'

SELECT 1 AS updateResults --if this is done after the UPDATE, a row doesn't get returned
```

My UPDATE query is valid and does what it's supposed to do.

I've also tried the "SELECT 'updateResults' = 1" format and tried putting a ; at the end of each statement and it didn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Here's the PHP code:

```
$updateSQL = "BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @result1 int
DECLARE @result2 int

--SELECT 1 AS updateResults --if this is here, the row gets returned

UPDATE theTable
    SET endDate = '" . $endDate . "'
    WHERE permitYear = '" . $permitYear . "'

UPDATE theTable
    SET startDate = '" . $startDate . "'
    WHERE permitYear = '" . $nextYear . "'

--Test to make sure both records were saved
SELECT @result1 = permitYear
    FROM theTable
    WHERE permitYear = '" . $permitYear . "'
    AND endDate = '" . $endDate . "'

SELECT @result2 = permitYear
    FROM theTable
    WHERE permitYear = '" . $nextYear . "'
    AND startDate = '" . $startDate . "'

if ((@result1 > 0) AND (@result2 > 0))
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        SELECT 1 AS updateResults
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT 0 AS updateResults
    END";

$updateRS = sqlsrv_query($con, $updateSQL);

if (!is_resource($updateRS)) {
    //There was a problem. A resource wasn't returned. It never fails here
    exit;
}

if (!sqlsrv_has_rows($updateRS)) {
    echo ("fail for no rows returned");
    exit;
}

$updateARR = sqlsrv_fetch_array($updateRS);

//It makes it here if the SELECT is done before the UPDATE
if ($updateARR['updateResults'] == '1') {
    //success
}
else {
    //save problem
}
```

Additional info: If I take out the 2 UPDATE statements it runs as expected and returns the updateResults row.

Comment: daft question maybe, but do you have the correct PHP command to execute multiple statements?

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: That's the query string.... but can we see the code that actually executes that query

Comment: Why are you checking to see if both records were inserted? The whole point of the transaction is it will rollback if either insert fails (i.e it will only commit if both inserts complete successfully)

Comment: Based on the success or failure, my PHP code does different things. I could have PHP do another test after this is run but that's another query and more network traffic.

Comment: Just use `sqlsrv_rows_affected` to see how many rows, if any, were inserted.

Comment: Are you sure the SQL block actually runs ? I would expect it to fail as the statements don't end on a ";". perhaps start with a single update statement, verify it actually works combined with this php code and then expand it from there ?

Comment: The block is running. Both updates are processed. I just tried your suggestion and put a ; at the end of each statement and it didn't make a difference. I did try a single update without any extra stuff added as outlined in the simplified version of my query that's at the top. Just an UPDATE and SELECT. If I take out the 2 UPDATE statements and my dates aren't actually changed when I run it, it runs as expected and returns the updateResults row.

Comment: This sql statement also works if it's run inside SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have "SET NOCOUNT ON" so the SQL messages such as "(1 row(s) affected)" were being returned before the SELECT results. My code should have been:

```
$updateSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ...
```

This way the SQL messages would be supressed.

As a side note, after I figured out the issue I noticed the following: Even though I wasn't using a stored procedure for this, I noticed when you create a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it even puts the following in the template for you:

```
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should query select like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 'updateResults' = 1
```

Comment: I'd not recommend putting quotes around 'updateResults' unless you want it to be treated as a string literal

Comment: I don't want to return a value from a table. SELECT 1 (or 0) AS updateResults is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in two SQL statements rather than one. Here's what I did:

I took out the SELECT x AS updateResults lines from the $updateSQL then:

```
$updateSQL = ...(same as the question, without the SELECT x AS updateResults lines)...

sqlsrv_query($con, $updateSQL);

$testSQL = "
DECLARE @result1 int
DECLARE @result2 int

SELECT @result1 = permitYear
FROM theTable
WHERE permitYear = '" . $permitYear . "'
    AND endDate = '" . $endDate . "'

SELECT @result2 = permitYear
FROM Transportation.dbo.PermitDate
WHERE permitYear = '" . $nextYear . "'
    AND startDate = '" . $startDate . "'

if ((@result1 > 0) AND (@result2 > 0))
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1 AS updateResults
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS updateResults
    END
";

$testRS = sqlsrv_query($con, $testSQL);

if (!is_resource($testRS)) {
    //There was a problem. A resource wasn't returned
}

if (!sqlsrv_has_rows($testRS)) {
    //fail for no rows
}

$testARR = sqlsrv_fetch_array($testRS);

if ($testARR['updateResults'] == '1') {
    //success
}
else {
    //fail - the changes were not saved
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reverse the order of the SELECT and UPDATE statements when they're part of the transaction? If not, I would try:

Instead of:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
SELECT 1 AS updateResults
```

Try:

```
SELECT 1 AS updateResults
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```